# Error on Task and timer c#

Tags: c#

Sir, Ma'am I have a problem. An error showed up: "The process cannot access the file 'C:\temps\1.pdf' because it is being used by another process." and what I wanted to do is to access that path without an error.

I have a folder named "temps", it is where I store my pdf.

My timer is set to 10 milliseconds. For every 10 milliseconds my command "SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE CustID=@ID && St=@stnow && Se=@sen" will execute and after that my DataAdapter "ad" will fill my dataset "ds" to be used by my ReportClass "report2"to export a pdf to my folder "temps".

Please enlighten me if there is something wrong with my code or the way I construct my code" Note: "This project is for improving my skills. I accept constructive criticism and I'm very thankful for your reply/replies."

Below is my code:

```
private void Elapsed_Time_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
  DateTime timeticking = DateTime.Now; // Just to check my time.
  Task t = new Task(() => getreport()); // run my function
  t.Start();
}

private void getreport()
{
  using (MySqlConnection con4 = new MySqlConnection(connString))
  {
   con4.Open();
   using (MySqlCommand com4 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM 
          schedule WHERE CustID=@ID && St 
          =@stnow && Se=@sen", con4))
    { 
     string status="Complete";
     string sentss="Ready";
     MySqlDataAdapter ad = new MySqlDataAdapter();
     com4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stnow", status);
     com4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sentss", sentss);
     com4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", CusID); 
     ad = new MySqlDataAdapter(com4);
     DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
     ad.Fill(ds.reporting_schedule);
     ReportClass report2 = new CrystalReport1();
     report2.SetDataSource(ds);
     report2.ExportToDisk
     (CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, 
     @"C:\\temps\\" + CusID + ".pdf"); //This is the error          
     report2.Close();
     com4.Dispose();
     ad.Dispose();
    }
  con4.close();
  }
}
```

If you have questions please let me know.

Comment: What if the run time of the task takes 15 milliseconds?  Do you really need to replace the file 100 times per second?

Comment: You use `CusID` in the query but `CustomerID` for the filename. Also, i don't see where you change the value of CusID either. Are you sure you are not just runing the query twice with the same values?

Comment: Hi. From where is `Elapsed_Time_Tick` being called? Whenever doing something in Parallel or in very quick succession (which might run in parallel) warrants trying to do it with a `lock`

Comment: Sir  Scott Chamberlain, about the CustomerID, I already fixed it. I forgot to change it when I was typing my code here.

Comment: Hi woelliJ!! I start the Elapsed_Time on FormLoad. I would like to do the parallel. Any suggestion where should I put it?

Comment: Sir Dave S, Thats what I really wanted to do.

Comment: I'm thanking all of you from bottom of my heart. I'm excited to learn

Comment: Is it the `ExportToDisk` call that's throwing the exception?

Comment: Hi Rufus, yes sir..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's one of your tasks that's locking the file and not some external process, you can use a [lock statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) to ensure that only one task can write to the file at a time:

```
// This object is used to ensure only one task can access the file at a time
private object fileLock = new object();

private void GetReport()
{
    // previous code omitted...

    // before we try to write to the file, we wait for our lock object to become available
    lock (fileLock)
    {
        report2.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat,
            @"C:\temps\" + CusID + ".pdf");
    }

    // later code omitted...
}
```

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement):

The lock keyword ensures that one thread does not enter a critical section of code while another thread is in the critical section. If another thread tries to enter a locked code, it will wait, block, until the object is released.